# jquery 1.6.4 is not compatible with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-1.6

Looks like jQuery 1.6.4 ain't working fine with ie8. What other version is suggested for ie8 ?

Comment: Have you thought of looking at the jQuery homepage and forums for help on this?

Comment: Why do you think it does not work and why don't you use the latest version anyway?

Comment: jQuery 1.6.4 (or infact, any version of jQuery) is very compatible with IE8 in my experience! Are you sure about this?

Comment: What doesn't work? Sounds like you've tested every single function.

Answer (score 2):

Below information is copied from **[jQuery 1.6.4 Released](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/12/jquery-1-6-4-released/)**

### jQuery 1.6.4 Change Log

The current change log of the 1.6.4 release.

**Data**
    • #10194: Data attribute names with single dash-surrounded letters cannot be accessed by the camel-case name

**Event**
    • #10208: $(“form”).live(“submit”, fn) not fired from  in IE8

**Support**
    • #10197: Bug with mime-type application/xhtml+xml in jquery 1.6.3

If you really tested in all angels and still if it not working then you can file a bug with JQuery **[file a bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/)** .

Refer this **[jQuery 1.6.4 Released](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/12/jquery-1-6-4-released/)** for more info.